# Is it possible to display dates in power query as MMM/YY and keep it as a date format instead of text?

Tags: powerquery, date-format, powerpivot

My problem is that I generated a pivot chart that is showing the axis values as DD/MM/YYYY. I changed the date format for the relevant column in the power pivot manager to MMM/YY and it looks fine in there, it's displayed correctly in the pivot table as well, but not on the chart axis. I'm guessing it's because in the main query the format is stuck as DD/MM/YYYY. I also tried to format the axis to a number & date in the chart, but it doesn't react. Can anyone help please?

[pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Av7R.png)

[pivot chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByFE2.png)

[pivot chart format settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh2GW.png)

Comment: Assuming your date column is [date], you could add a custom column in powerquery with formula = #date (Date.Year[date],Date.Month[date],1)   in order to get rid of the day number and perhaps that will work

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem from the information you have provided.  I suggest you create sample data that can be copy/pasted into and Excel workbook; then transformed with Power Query and loaded as a pivot table/chart. Might help to read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).